# How to access session from Rails Integration Test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, session, integration-testing

Consider the following integration test:

```
test "if there is no user in session, redirect to index and flash message" do
  open_session do |sess|
    post '/login', :email => users(:client).email, :password => 'rumpelstiltskin'
    sess[:user] = nil
    get '/user_page'
    assert_redirected_to index_path
    assert_equal "Your session has expired. Please log in again", flash[:notice]
  end    
end
```

This generates error: `undefined method '[]='`

And, changing to `sess.session[:user] = nil` generates an error as well: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'session' for nil:NilClass`

How do you modify the session params from an integration test in Rails?

Working in Rails 3.0.7, Ruby 1.9.2p180, Unit test framework.

EDIT:
`get '/user_page', nil, {:user => nil}` and `get ('/user_page', nil, {:user => nil} )` generate errors.

Comment: Is this unit testing or integration testing? :)

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 3.2.3 the following seems to work for me:

```
# Hit the root_path to start our session
get root_path

# A helper method to set our session
login_as(@user_fixture)

# Now we can access the session variable
assert session[:user_id]
```

Not sure if this will work for you, so goodluck!

Answer (score 3):

Just use `session[:user]` without `open_session` block

Comment: `session[:user] = nil` does not pass the updated session to the controller.

Comment: this works in rails 2, but not rails 3 (which is the version being used in the question).

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that it does not seem possible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what integration tests are designed for. You shouldn't modify the session directly, instead you should hit your /logout path.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about accessing `session`.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky - Yes, and I said don't access session, it's wrongheaded. I wrote this 2 years ago, but I think I still stand by it.